# Fill input form value in modal

Tags: jquery, forms, input, modal-dialog, hidden

I have a modal that contains a form. I need to pass an id_code in a hidden input field but I'm not able to do that.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {         

$('#inpage_form').live ('click', function () {
    var test=$(this).attr('id_passed'); 

    $.modal ({ 
        div: '#inpage_form_container' 
        , title: test
        , overlayClose: true

    });
});}
```

And this is the html which is calling the modal:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id_passed="'+dCodArt+'" id="inpage_form" class="trigger"><input type="checkbox">
```

id_passed is recovered in another jQuery script and passed as a js var.

Here is the modal form:

```
<div id="inpage_form_container" style="display: none" onload="initForm(document.forms[0], 'codArt', 'test');">

    <form action="./goTransaction.asp" method="post" class="form" id="formdue" >
    <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="r">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<%=request.servervariables("URL")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="numOrd" value="<%=numOrd%>">
    <input type="hidden" id="codArt" name="codArt">
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried Googling and after spending the morning on it was not able to solve this problem.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use HTML5 `data` attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-title="+dCodArt+" id="inpage_form" class="trigger">

var test = $('#inpage_form').data('title');
```

Comment: thanks raminson but the problem is related to the value which should populate

<input type="hidden" id="codArt" name="codArt"> 

i m already able to fill the modal title passing it through the title variable setting it to "test" var.